# How do I add ipv6 support for HTTP::AppServer?

Tags: perl, http, ipv6

I have a http server that uses the module [HTTP::AppServer](http://search.cpan.org/~kitomer/HTTP-AppServer-0.04/lib/HTTP/AppServer.pm) from cpan.

I can connect to my server using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, while it miserably fails with `::1`.

Here are some example with curl:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html
This is a test.
$ curl -g http://[::1]:8080/index.html
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

This is how the server is started:

```
use HTTP::AppServer;
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

  my $server = HTTP::AppServer->new( StartBackground => 0, ServerPort => 8080 );

  $server->plugin('FileRetriever', DocRoot => '/tmp');

  $server->start;
```

Actually it is a lot more complicated. But it I don't think all the rest of the script is necessary. I've added the module [IO::Socket::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/IO-Socket-IP-0.16/lib/IO/Socket/IP.pm) and upgraded the module Socket to the version found [here](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Socket-2.002/Socket.pm) in order to make IO::Socket::IP to work.

Still, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After LeoNerd saying that IO::Socket::IP can't help me in this situation, I've found an alternative solution, although this solution works only with some perl version.

HTTP::AppServer is based on HTTP::Server::Simple and I found on cpan a newer version of this second module that supports ipv6.

First of all you need to download the newer version of HTTP::Server::Simple here:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Server::Simple](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aServer%3a%3aSimple)

As you can see, it has a different `new` method that accept a new argument `family`.

Now you have to take the HTTP::AppServer.pm and modify the `init` function from

```
sub init
{
    my ($self, %opts) = @_;

    # server options defaults
    my %defaults = (StartBackground => 0, ServerPort => 3000);

    # set options or use defaults
    map { $self->{$_} = (exists $opts{$_} ? $opts{$_} : $defaults{$_}) }
        keys %defaults;

    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'});

    return $self;
}
```

to

```
sub init
{
    my ($self, %opts) = @_;

    # server options defaults
    my %defaults = (StartBackground => 0, ServerPort => 3000);

    # set options or use defaults
    map { $self->{$_} = (exists $opts{$_} ? $opts{$_} : $defaults{$_}) }
        keys %defaults;

    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'}, Socket::AF_INET6);

    return $self;
}
```

Unfortunately, this answer the question, but not my problem because it doesn't work with perl 5.8.8 also upgrading Socket.pm to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Perl version newer than 5.14.

http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-ipv6.html

Comment: Sorry, I can't. My software will run on machine that still have perl 5.8.8. I have to guarantee compatibility with that perl version.

Comment: I've edited my code to use IO::Socket::IP but it still doesn't listen on ipv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, it may be a bug somewhere in either `IO::Socket::IP` or `HTTP::AppServer`. Can you send it to me as an RT bug on `IO::Socket::IP`, and I'll take a look into it.

https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Queue=IO-Socket-IP

Comment: Done. I also provided you with a minimal runnable application. So you can have all files at hand. Thank you very much.